# C++ scope resolution operator before funcions

Tags: c++, scope-resolution-operator

```
namespace Test {
    struct T {};
    void F(T t) {}
};

int main() {
    Test::T t;
    F(t); // Why no `Test::`?
}
```

Why there is no need of `Test::` before `F(t)`?

What is the rule behind this?

Comment: [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

Comment: That's exactly what ADL try to achieve. Imagine you are using an operator overload?